# How to prevent the middle-button from opening a new tab in the browser?

Tags: html, ajax, browser, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have a group of links on a page. when the user clicks a link it triggers an asynchronous request and a content area on the page is updated with the response html.

This works fine, except for if the user clicks the link with the 'middle-button' (or mouse wheel, whatever it's called!). Then a new tab opens and the response gets returned and rendered to that tab.

Is there any way for me to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

catch the link with javascript and override the default link behaviour.

like this:

```
$('a.ajax').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // do ajax stuff, and add an onfinish function that does
   // something like document.location.href = this.attr('href');
});
```

You don't have to do the document.location.href, as I just noticed that a content area is updated. Just catch the default behaviour with the e.preventDefault();

// edit
The preventDefault won't stop the middle mouse button... Have you considered not using  tags? I know it should be accessible so maybe a span containing the link, so you can add the onclick event on the span and hide the link with css?

Comment: I implemented your suggestion to add a link to a span. It's not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, Javascript wont have access to that sort of control for security reasons as it would be wide open for abuse.

Comment: It's also just down right annoying to the user expecting his normal browser behaviour (ie. what he asked for) - if they're using accessibility tools it's even worse.

Comment: @Rushyo There are some legitimate uses for this, such as a ajax link that would not make sense to be opened in it's own window.  You want it to look and feel like a link, and use a link tag to support accessibility, but you want clicking it to always issue an ajax request, and never actually navigate to that location in its own tab.

Comment: @AaronLS You've got two objectives there: Provide accessibility support and provide a click event. Separate the two. A link that isn't a link that pretends to be a link is not providing accessibility, it's a hack out of laziness to trick conformance checkers and it has all kinds of weird semantics that make it unsuitable for an accessible, semantically-clean web page.

Comment: @AaronLS ..which is still only a side show to the actual issue: Don't mess about with the user's expected behaviour. If they wanted nothing to happen then they wouldn't have middle-clicked. All you do is create user confusion ("why is nothing happening?") at best and user annoyance ("you've actively prevented me from triggering my middle-click add-on!") at worst.

Comment: @Rushyo If nothing is happening then your web application is poorly designed.  You obviously wouldn't have a link that doesn't perform some type of navigation.  If you look at gmail, there are plenty of cases where middle click doesn't open a new window, but something does happen that is interactive.

Comment: @Rushyo Yes it can be misused, but just about every feature of javascript can be misused.  That does't make every black bird a crow.

Comment: @Rushyo From your description, it sounds like when you create interactive AJAX web apps, you avoid links at all costs and instead you use what?  Buttons?  No, you are violating the semantics of a button that by default performs a form submit.  You wire click events on divs or other display elements?  No, that would violate the semantics of a display element.  What would you use to navigate a web app that resides at a single URL and consists of interactive elements?  All of those approaches would be inaccessible.  It wouldn't be apparent to screen reader that a display element is interactive.

Comment: @Rushyo If you are going to issue ajax requests, you need to wire up to interactive elements.  There is no two ways around that.  AJAX in itself violates all kinds of semantics.  It seems standard now, but in the beginning is was itself a hack.  HTML and browsers don't really support it natively, it is all javascript magic.  Issueing a request with some javascript, and then manipulating the DOM to display the result.  Wiring up to elements and giving them a completely different behavior than what their specs describe.

Comment: I would add that this answer is on two counts wrong.  "Unfortunately no"  Yes, as per the other answer, JavaScript supports this.  "for security reasons", on what grounds?

Comment: I agree that this feature can easily be misused, but I don't see that one can say that you should never use it.

Comment: "HTML and browsers don't really support it natively, it is all javascript magic." I stopped reading there. Have a nice day and all that.